# Auto generate serial numbers in sql

Tags: sql, serial-number

```
table orders
+----+--------+------------+
|s.no|   id   |  ordername |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |   34   |    name    |      
+----+--------+------------+
|  2 |   35   |    name    |        
+----+--------+------------+
|  3 |   36   |    name    |        
+----+--------+------------+
|  4 |   37   |    name    |        
+----+--------+------------+
|  5 |   38   |    name    |       
+----+--------+------------+
```

write query for auto generate serial numbers and when i delete an order from sql so serial numbers should be as 1234567 in serial_number row and i used order id as auto increment

Comment: Answer: Yes, someone can write this query.

Comment: Changing the numbers in the data sounds like a bad idea.  You can just assign a sequential number when querying the table.

Comment: can you write query here for this

Comment: This is probably better handled in a view since your serial no column will be changing.  Look into using a row number for this -- this is very much database specific though.

Answer (score 5):

You can write the query in most dialects of sql as:

```
select row_number() over (order by id) as "s.no",
       id, ordername
from orders o
```

Here is syntax that works in SQL Server:

```
with toupdate as (
      select row_number() over (order by id) as newval,
             o.*
      from orders o
     )
update toupdate set [s.no] = newval;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but how i can add data in s.no row in sql

Answer (score 1):

**FOR MYSQL USERS**
Based on your reasons for not wanting to use user defined variables as wanting to avoid having 2 queries, one for inializing and one to use it you could use the following:

```
SELECT  @a:=@a+1 serial_number, 
        marks 
FROM    student_marks,
        (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select @a:=0;
SELECT  @a:=@a+1 serial_number,
    marks 
FROM      student_marks,
```

It works for me hope i will for for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below query, it gives you serial number without any partition. I am using MSSQL server to generate the serial number.

```
Select row_number() over( order by (select null)) [serialno],
id,
ordername
from orders With(nolock)
```

Hope this would work for you.